# Array and Array[0] confusion

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-to-array

In the following C code:

```
char test[] ={'T','e','s','t'};

printf("%d\n",test == &test[0]); // Returns 1 - Okay as array varaible holds address of first element
```

So shouldn't the following should print the same?:

```
printf("value of test %c\n", test); // prints - '|' not even in the array
printf("value of test[0] %c\n", test[0]); // prints - 'T'
```

Not even that, even these prints different values:

```
printf("value of test %p\n", test); // contains a address 0x7ffee9b22b7c
printf("value of test[0] %p\n", test[0]); // also conatains 0x100
```

What is happening?

thanks

Comment: An array variable *does not* hold the address of its first element. An array variable holds the values of all its elements. An array *expression*, in most but not all context, "decays" to a pointer expression that yields the address of its first (0th) element. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pointer decay**

While pointers and arrays are different types of variables, the array variable is often implicitly converted as pointer to its first element. This is called [array to pointer decay](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array).

This is what is happening in the comparison you make between `test` and `&test[0]`: `test` decays to a pointer which can be compared to `&test[0]`, and their value are equal

**What is happening in your [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) calls ?**

```
printf("value of test %c\n", test); // prints - '|' not even in the array
printf("value of test[0] %c\n", test[0]); // prints - 'T'
```

The first ones with the conversion specifier `%c` converts the argument to `unsigned char` and prints the character.
In the first line you print `test` as a character and in the second line you print `test[0]` as a character.

The type of `test[0]` is indeed a `char` so the correct character (the `T`) gets printed. However the type of `test` is an array of `char`, which in this case, also decays to a pointer. In your execution of the test this pointer happens have the value of `0x7ffee9b22b7c`. This value is then converted to `unsigned char` so the last byte of your pointer is kept, in that case that's `7c` which happens to be the ASCII code for character `|`.

Note that since it depends on the value of the pointer it is very likely that you will get a different character printed every time you run the program (some of them might even not be printable characters).

The two results are different because they are different things : one is a character and the other is a pointer (in this case a pointer to a character).

`test[0]` is the *value that is contained* at the beginning of the array, while `test` is evaluated as a pointer to the first element (and then forcibly converted to a character). As you noted earlier, the `test`  is equivalent to `&test[0]` and *not* to `test[0]`.

`test[0]` is equivalent to `*test` (or to `*(test + 0)`). In general in an array, `array[i]` will be equivalent to `*(array +i)`.

Comment: Mismatched argument and specifier types in `printf()` lead to undefined behavior, so attempting to print `test` here with `%c` is UB. Note also that _conversion specifiers_ convert values to printed representations, but do not convert the types of the arguments. The lone exception to this rule is the `%c` specifier, which does, as you say, convert its argument to `unsigned char`, but this is after the argument has already been converted to `int` by the _default argument promotions_ (applied to arguments of variadic functions).

Answer (score 2):

You sort of answered your own question in the first example:

```cpp
test == &test[0]

test != test[0] // otherwise, test[0] would have to be equal to &test[0]
```

I.e., the *value* of `test` (interpreted as pointer) equals the *address* of `test[0]`. Therefore, your following examples can't be true, since that would mean that for either of those its value would equal its own address, which doesn't make sense!

(Note: The following addresses are examples of course.)

| Expression | Type | Value interpreted as character `%c` | Value interpreted as pointer `%p` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `test` | `char*` | *nonsensical* | `0x1000` |
| `&test` | `char**` | *nonsensical* | `0x2000` |
| `test[0]` | `char` | `T` | *nonsensical* |
| `&test[0]` | `char*` | *nonsensical* | `0x1000` |
| `test[1]` | `char` | `e` | *nonsensical* |
| `&test[1]` | `char*` | *nonsensical* | `0x1001` |
| `test[2]` | `char` | `s` | *nonsensical* |
| `&test[2]` | `char*` | *nonsensical* | `0x1002` |
| `test[3]` | `char` | `t` | *nonsensical* |
| `&test[3]` | `char*` | *nonsensical* | `0x1003` |

Note: For the purpose of understanding your initial problem, it's OK to look at `test` as `char*`, and therefore `&test` as `char**`. However, in reality it is a little bit more complex, and `test` is actually of type `char(*)[4]`. This makes a difference with `sizeof` for example.

Comment: Is test[0] equivalent to *(test + 0)? 

So test[0] is the value while test is an address.

Comment: Yes. That's right. (Technically, `test` is an array name, but for _most_ intents and purposes it can be interpreted as a pointer, i.e. an address. See "pointer decay" in Louen's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

you might be confusing yourself with how you are printing. Try this and see if it's easier to follow.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

    char test[] = "Test\n\0"; // an array that contains char values
    char *testptr; // a pointer that can point to a place in memory that contains a char value


    printf(test); // by default it will print all of the char values starting with test[0]

    testptr = &test[2]; // the pointer now points to the third position in the char array

    printf(testptr); // print the test array starting with the pointers position

}
```